# iOS Swift ; stops AVFoundation repeats

Tags: ios, swift

When *the sound starts it doesn't stop*,
how can I stop it?

```
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer2 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("filename", ofType: "aiff")!)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    audioPlayer2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: Sound2, error: nil)
    audioPlayer2.prepareToPlay()    }

fund update() { ~ ~ ~ ~

audioPlayer2.play()

}
```

and I tried

```
audioPlayer2.stop()
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use AVPlayer:

```
var player:AVPlayer!
var steamingURL:NSURL = NSURL(string:playerURL)
player = AVPlayer(URL: steamingURL)
player.play()
```